# Where can a person find help in developing a nuclear drive for space travel?

Tags: discussion, moderator

Sometimes my most complex thoughts are when I sleep. Just before I wake like an Epiphany recently. I thought of type of drive that can split one atom at a time behind a shield using an atom injector. I had the entire problem solved and have many questions, but I would quickly wear out my privileges here. Down side of dreaming its hard to remember the fine details. I admit I do not have the schooling or know how to realize this technology. Where can I find help piecing the technology and memory it would require to make it work?

Comment: Consider looking up fission fragment reactors, which operate on a scale of reaction mass between your dream and normal fission reactors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### This is not the place to discuss this. Meta is to discuss how we handle  space.stackexchange.

<sub>You are a veeeeery loooong way from being able to study that. So start by the basics in math and physics. http://khanacademy.org can help, or other mooc.</sub>